# Why does ENS register names as hashes?

Tags: solidity, ens

There is a similar question in their [FAQ](https://docs.ens.domains/frequently-asked-questions)

> Why are names registered as hashes?
>
> Hashes provide a fixed length identifier that can easily be passed around between contracts with fixed overhead and no issues passing around variable-length strings.

I think it's pretty vague. What makes "fixed length identifier"s easier to pass between contracts? Predictable/fixed gas costs?

And what are these "issues passing around variable-length strings"?

Why did they choose bytes32 as the identifiers when most domains are only a few bytes long? I guess it's cool to have a fixed/predictable byte length, but at the cost of that size being longer than most domains? It would have been more practical to just use the domain string as the identifier, and if your domain was long for some reason, you just pay more gas. I am trying to learn why they designed it this way.

Comment: The EVM stores everything as 32-bytes long words. It's more gas efficient to store anything this way (though there are some exceptions).